# How to target inside div children

Tags: javascript, event-handling

I have multiple divs as buttons which I use loop and `addEventListener`  to trigger `MouseOver`  and `MouseOut` event but could not target the child inside the divs thank you for your help

```
var btn = document.querySelectorAll('.c-btn');
var btnback = document.querySelectorAll('.btnback');

for (i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
  btn[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function(event){
    this.classList.add("rotatinEffect");
    btchild[i].style.backgroundColor = 'red'
  });

  btn[i].addEventListener("mouseout", function(){
    console.log('out')
    this.classList.remove("rotatinEffect");
    btchild[i].style.backgroundColor = 'blue'
  });
}
```

Comment: where is `btchild` defined?

Comment: Use `this.childNodes[0]` for the first child  instead of `btchild[i]`

Comment: btchild inisde .c-btn which are buttons and btchild is background for c-btns.thank you